# How to use a ViewPager with CollapsingToolbar without using NestedScrollView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to make several fragments in the main activity each having a RecyclerView such that I can swipe between them. Also in this activity, I have a collapsing toolbar on top of all these things.

1. I tried using the RecyclerView Directly inside the ViewPager but unfortunately the Toolbar didn't Collapse (I think it needs a NestedScrollView)
2. I added NestedScrollView outside the ViewPager which gave me an Exception on adding new items to any of the RecyclerViews   `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` which I found to be a bug caused by calling `runOnUiThread()` but if I loaded data using UI thread it would be too slow
3. I tried using NestedScrollViews inside each fragment (wrapping the RecyclerViews) but it gave the same exception

Is there any way to collapse the toolbar without NestedScrollView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look with this `layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lnr_expandView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:minHeight="130dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7">

            </LinearLayout>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                app:collapseIcon="@drawable/ic_back"
                app:contentInsetStart="30dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/googlesans_medium"
                    android:padding="@dimen/pad_15"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Your 2nd parent child layout must contains this attribute for collapse effect;

```
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Comment: I tried this and didn't work but your answer inspired me to try using a FrameLayout instead of the LinearLayout then it worked. Edit your answer and I will accept it. Thanks